Dynamically generate new color On BackColor Text lable C# windows Form
I work in a POS system for restaurants, and to facilitate the sorting process, I want all types of category to be a different color.
image of result
I want a code that can generate a random back-color and then have each item be a uniform color

Does this answer your question? How to make Custom color in c#?

No, it not my answer , I need random color for each category label from database @AlgoRythm

Use the answer from that question and simply generate random numbers to create the colors. Limit the random numbers to ones which will generate nice colors.

@Mohamed Babiker.
To set random color for each category label from database, you could follow these steps:
Retrieve the category labels and their corresponding comma-separated RGB color values from the database.
Parse the RGB color values and convert them into Color objects.
Generate random colors for each category label.
Assign the random colors to the category labels.
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += Form1_Load;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Assuming you have a method to retrieve category labels and their colors from the database
        Dictionary<string, string> categoryColors = GetCategoryColorsFromDatabase();

        // Generate random colors for each category label
        Random random = new Random();
        int top = 10;
        Label label;
        foreach (var categoryLabel in categoryColors.Keys)
        {
            // Parse the RGB color value from the database
            string[] rgbValues = categoryColors[categoryLabel].Split(',');
            int red = int.Parse(rgbValues[0]);
            int green = int.Parse(rgbValues[1]);
            int blue = int.Parse(rgbValues[2]);

            // Create a Color object using the parsed RGB values
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);

            label = new Label();
            label.Text = categoryLabel;
            label.BackColor = color;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.Height = 50;
           
            label.Location = new Point(50, top);
            top += 80;
            Controls.Add(label);
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> GetCategoryColorsFromDatabase()
    {
        // Simulated database query
        return new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Category 1", "150,250,70" },
            { "Category 2", "100,200,150" },
            { "Category 3", "200,100,50" }
            // Add more category labels and their colors as needed
        };
    }
}


The result:

